# Bought games don't show up in library on new PC

Tags: steam, pc

I've got some problems with my steam library.

After buying a new pc, I logged into my steam account there and downloaded a few of my games I was in the mood of playing, including some free games and one of my paid games (Game Dev Tycoon). This was a few months ago. When I wanted to download the others, they weren't in my library, the free games (e.g. TF2 or Duel links), as well as the paid games (e.g. Mega Man X Legacy Collection, Portal 1+2 and Table Top Simulator).
When I searched for them in the Steam store, I could simply download the free ones, but there is a price shown for the paid games.

In the Steam forums and StackExchange, I found two tips I already checked: Being logged into a wrong account or having the wrong filters.
I checked whether I was in the right account by changing my avatar on one pc and checking whether it changed on the other one, which was the case. Also, as I mentioned before, I still have one of the games I bought. My account info also aligns.
On my old pc, when I use the standard filters with tools hidden, steam shows me that 19/114 objects are shown (all of my games minus the tools). With the same filters on my new pc, it only shows that 8/104 objects are shown. If I disable said filter, the hidden tools, which I didn't ever download, btw, are shown, but no games other than those that were shown with the filter.

Do you guys have an idea? It doesn't help that I can't really contact Steam support anymore and their self-help guide doesn't really work in my browser

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem some time ago, I'm not sure if this will help you but all I did was go to the steam folder (Usually C:\Program Files\Steam or C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam) and delete "ClientRegistry.blob". This makes steam reinstall the current update and you should be good to go.

If that doesn't help, definitely try reinstalling steam.

Comment: Thanks for your tip!
Is this file supposed to be directly inside of the Steam folder or in one of the subfolders? I couldn't find it in the folder itself

Comment: I reinstalled Steam and now the games I had on this PC are gone too

Comment: @Yama994 Yeah, if you uninstall Steam with all your games still in `Steam/steamapps/`, it nukes them. You can use Steam Library Folders to help prevent this in the future by having games installed outside of the Steam folder.

Comment: @l3l_aze do you know of a way to get any of my games back (except manually transfering them)?

Comment: Since you uninstalled everything already they need to be downloaded again. To keep them separate from the Steam install in the future, you can use a [Steam Library Folder](https://www.technipages.com/how-to-add-a-new-steam-library-folder/amp). On Windows and Linux any extra folder has to be on a separate hard drive, but on Mac OS X it may not care. There are third-party tools like [Steam Library Manager](https://github.com/RevoLand/Steam-Library-Manager), but it's really not hard to [do it manually](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/5khih1/file_moving_questions/dbo24w6?context=3).